# RSpec test for redirect returns 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test this method that redirects to the same page but with a www. prefix if it's not there. 
It does the redirect, but the RSpec test returns "Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>." Why is that?

application_controller.rb

```
  def check_uri
    if request.subdomain.present? and request.subdomain.first != "www"
      redirect_to request.protocol + "www." + request.host_with_port + request.fullpath if !/^www/.match(request.host)
    end
  end
```

application_controller_spec.rb #

```
  describe :check_uri do
    it "should redirect to www" do
      { :get => "http://sub.lvh.me:3000/accounts/sign_up" }.
        should redirect_to "http://www.sub.lvh.me:3000/accounts/sign_up"
    end
  end
```

When I debug I get:
(

```
rdb:1) p response
#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x0000010277d988 @writer=#<Proc:0x0000010277c678@/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@evergreen/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:43 (lambda)>, @block=nil, @length=0, @header={}, @status=200, @body=[], @cookie=[], @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @cache_control={}, @etag=nil>
```

Comment: Did you debug the response? What's the content for response.body?

Comment: do you have check_uri as a `before_filter` in application_controller?

Comment: Yes, check_uri is called via before_filter. I added the debug response to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test the header location of the response?

```
 response.header["Location"].should eq("http://www.sub.lvh.me:3000/accounts/sign_up"
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Your test is not hitting the method `check_uri` that you defined in application_controller.rb, because RSpec runs with a default test host, e.g. "test.host" on port 80.

You should call an action that is present in your application controller and stub the request host and port like this:

```
describe :check_uri do
  it "should redirect to www" do
    @request.host = 'sub.lvh.me'
    @request.port = 3000

    get :index

    expect(response).to redirect_to "http://www.sub.lvh.me:3000/accounts/sign_up"
  end
end
```